# laravel 8.x - sail - for mysql a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, wsl-2, laravel-sail

when running laravel 8.x sail on WSL2 in a Win10 env i ran into the above error and wanted to document the simple solution as i could not find any relevant issues reported by other on the subject on here or laracasts discussion forum

full error output:

```
ERROR: for clkclct_mysql_1  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

ERROR: for mysql  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.25/containers/2e424320d1b88df13c77559c8021305ed82bc578045c37dd7da199f593e4c45e/start
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open Task Manager
2. expand 'More Details' in bottom left
3. got to the 'services' tab
4. find MySQL (you can filter alphabetically)
5. right click and select 'Stop'
6. re-run `sail up` command